# Set number of rows shown in console with print command

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10000, y=1:10000, z=1:10000)
print(df)

...
330 330 330 330
331 331 331 331
332 332 332 332
333 333 333 333
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 667 rows ]
```

How can i set the number of rows (50 for example) of a data frame i want to be printed into the console?

Regards

Comment: By changing the option setting? See `help("option")`.

Comment: Or use the `max` parameter of `print.data.frame`.

Comment: Try `head(df, 50)`.

Comment: or you can convert your `dataframe` into a `tibble`.

Comment: @carlo_sguera i already tried that, but that doesnt print out all the rows in the console.

Comment: @AlexB and then do what? How can i control the output in console with print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `n` argument in `print()` in tibbles.

```r
library(tibble)

iris_tbl <- as_tibble(iris)
```

```r
print(iris_tbl)
```

```
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 140 more rows
```

```r
print(iris_tbl, n = 30)
```

```
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa 
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2 setosa 
13          4.8         3            1.4         0.1 setosa 
14          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa 
15          5.8         4            1.2         0.2 setosa 
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4 setosa 
17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4 setosa 
18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3 setosa 
19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3 setosa 
20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3 setosa 
21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2 setosa 
22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4 setosa 
23          4.6         3.6          1           0.2 setosa 
24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5 setosa 
25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2 setosa 
26          5           3            1.6         0.2 setosa 
27          5           3.4          1.6         0.4 setosa 
28          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2 setosa 
29          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2 setosa 
30          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2 setosa 
# ... with 120 more rows
```